# Can't access header file in MoPub iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, mopub

I am new to Xcode and iOS development at all. I added iOS SDK from mopub in Xcode game project but it can't access the header files, don't know what is going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not imported MoPubSDK folder correctly. Delete it (the blue folder in the navigation panel) and import again the folder dragging. Select "create grop" and "copy items if needed" when you are asked.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have imported the MoPubSDK as  group and deleted the old blue folder. Done the clear build and got the same error
Here the way you asked to import the SDK: https://imgur.com/a/L8rMpUk
Here the error log image: https://imgur.com/a/LK9d5et

Comment: here the MoPub integration Guide which I tried to follow https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/ios/integrate/

Comment: @OusafAhmad change the line for #import "MPMoPubConfiguration.h", without the path. But you'd better use CocoaPods. You have the instructions in the link.

Comment: Now it works thanks for your help, btw what's the difference between group and folder?

Comment: @Ousaf Ahmad that blue folders are asset to include in the app. Or not to include, but the code sources are in groups.